# SLD not valid inside of GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, sld

I created a  SLD file and it does not run at all inside of GeoServer. Schematically it looks all there:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version= "1.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
    xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld"
    xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <NamedLayer>
      <Name>FireHydrants</Name>
       <UserStyle>
        <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
            <Name>500</Name>
          <Description>
            <Title>Fire Hydrants</Title>
          </Description>
            <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
              <ogc:PropertyName>flow_class</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>500</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
         </ogc:Filter>
        <PointSymbolizer>
           <Graphic>
             <Mark>
              <WellKnownName>triangle</WellKnownName>
            <sld:Fill>
              <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#00FFFF</sld:CssParameter>
            </sld:Fill>
             </Mark>
           <Size>11</Size>
            </Graphic>
        </PointSymbolizer>
       </Rule>
       <Rule>
        <Name>501-1000</Name>
        <Description>
          <Title>501 to 1000</Title>
        </Description>
           <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
             <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>flow_class</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>501</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
            <ogc:PropertyName>flow_class</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>1000</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
            </ogc:Filter>
        <PointSymbolizer>
            <Graphic>
               <Mark>
                <WellKnownName>triangle</WellKnownName>
                        <sld:Fill>
            <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#ffa000</sld:CssParameter>
                     </sld:Fill>
                   </Mark>
            <Size>11</Size>
            </Graphic>
        </PointSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
    <Rule>
        <Name>1001-1500</Name>
        <Description>
          <Title>1001 to 1500</Title>
        </Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>flow_class</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>1001</ogc:Literal>
             </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
             <ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
            <ogc:PropertyName>flow_class</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>1500</ogc:Literal>
             </ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
            </ogc:Filter>
            <sld:MaxScaleDenominator>2134</sld:MaxScaleDenominator>
           <PointSymbolizer>
            <Graphic>
               <Mark>
                  <WellKnownName>triangle</WellKnownName>
                <sld:Fill><CssParameter name="fill">#33CC33</CssParameter>
                </sld:Fill>
                   </Mark>
                <Size>11</Size>
            </Graphic>
            </PointSymbolizer>
          </Rule>
      <Rule>
        <Name>1500</Name> 
        <Description>
            <Title>1500</Title>
        </Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
        <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
            <ogc:PropertyName>flow_class</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>1500</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
        </ogc:Filter>
        <PointSymbolizer>
           <Graphic>
               <Mark>
            <WellKnownName>triangle</WellKnownName>
         <sld:Fill><sld:CssParameter name="fill">#004785</sld:CssParameter>
            </sld:Fill>
                   </Mark>
                 <Size>11</Size>
            </Graphic>
        </PointSymbolizer>
`
    </Rule>
    <Rule>
       <Name>UNKNOWN</Name>
         <Description>
        <Title>UNKNOWN</Title>
         </Description>
        <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
         <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
         <ogc:PropertyName>UNKNOWN</ogc:PropertyName>
         </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
           </ogc:Filter>
        <PointSymbolizer>
           <Graphic>
             <Mark>
            <WellKnownName>triangle</WellKnownName>
                  <sld:Fill><sld:CssParameter name="fill">#ffa000</sld:CssParameter>
            </sld:Fill>
              </Mark>
               <Size>11</Size>
               </Graphic>
        </PointSymbolizer>
      </Rule>

          </FeatureTypeStyle>
        </UserStyle>
     </NamedLayer>
    </StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

any thoughts of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

There is a bad character before the last ("UNKNOWN") rule:

```
        </PointSymbolizer>
` <-------------------------------------------------------
    </Rule>
    <Rule>
       <Name>UNKNOWN</Name>
```

Comment: Also note that you use 'sld' as a namespace prefix, but you don't point define the associated namespace like `xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld"`

Comment: Okay.code looks a lot better-however i keep getting this validation error--->"line 72: cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'ogc:PropertyIsLessThan'. No child element is expected at this point". what does this mean? thanks !

Comment: It may mean an error in SLD but it can also mean that the SLD is OK but the validator is not up-to-date. The validator tends to give false negatives, Save the SLD and check with the layer preview application if it works despite the error messages.